# TailwindCSS: SVG icon won't resize properly

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I have been trying to resize the icon in this example.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-indigo-dark">
  <div class="flex text-grey-lighter">
    <svg class="flex-no-shrink fill-current" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100px" height="100px">
      <path d="M5 5a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v2A5 5 0 0 1 5 7V5zM0 16.68A19.9 19.9 0 0 1 10 14c3.64 0 7.06.97 10 2.68V20H0v-3.32z"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="leading-normal">
      Some demo text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, whatever I try I can't get the svg to resize. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's width and height attributes on the svg element. You can change those...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resize the icon, resize the `viewBox`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bg-indigo-dark">
  <div class="flex text-grey-lighter">

    <svg 
      class="flex-no-shrink fill-current" 
      fill="none" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 80 80"  
      width="100px" 
      height="100px"
    >
      <path d="M5 5a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v2A5 5 0 0 1 5 7V5zM0 16.68A19.9 19.9 0 0 1 10 14c3.64 0 7.06.97 10 2.68V20H0v-3.32z"/>
    </svg>

    <div class="leading-normal">
      Some demo text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's now  flex-shrink-0  https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/pull/85

Answer (score 22):

#### Changing SVG width and height in TailwindCSS

[Adam Wathan (TailwindCSS creator) solution for working with SVGs is presented in a video here.](https://tailwindcss.com/course/working-with-svg-icons/) His solution is as follows:

#### Steps to change SVG element

1. Remove width and height attributes
2. Add TailwindCSS width and height classes

#### Example of SVG in question

I've taken the SVG in the question and paired it down to just the SVG and abbreviated the path. Then making the above changes.

Before

```html
<svg class="flex-no-shrink fill-current"
     fill="none" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     width="100px" height="100px">  <!-- 1. Remove width and height attributes -->
  <path d="M5 5a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v2A5..."/>
</svg>
```

After

```html
   <!--      \/---- 2. Add tailwindcss width and height classes -->
<svg class="h-4 w-4 flex-no-shrink fill-current"
     fill="none" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M5 5a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v2A5..."/>
</svg>
```

He doesn't mention the viewbox other than to say it's easier if you keep it square.

Answer (score 5):

You need to first fix the viewbox--it's too big. That's what's giving you the extra padding. Then set the width and height as desired. See the snippet below:

```js
function changeHandler(event){
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
  svg.setAttribute("width", event.target.value + 'px');
  svg.setAttribute("height", event.target.value + 'px');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="number" value="20" onchange="changeHandler(event)" />
<div class="bg-indigo-dark">
  <div class="flex text-grey-lighter">
    <svg id="svg" class="flex-no-shrink fill-current" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20px" height="20px">
      <path d="M5 5a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v2A5 5 0 0 1 5 7V5zM0 16.68A19.9 19.9 0 0 1 10 14c3.64 0 7.06.97 10 2.68V20H0v-3.32z"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="leading-normal">
      Some demo text
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by changing `width` and `height` in:

```
<svg class="flex-no-shrink fill-current" fill="none" xmlns=
"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="50px" height="50px">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/58Lbqzh1/

Comment: Yeah but still something looks wrong. When I change it to for example width="200px" height="200px" the svg becomes bigger but I also see a large padding on the bottom and to the right. Where does that come from?

Comment: @sanders I see what you mean. It's something to do with the SVG, because when I try a jpg, that doesn't happen.

Comment: @sanders I had better luck when I changed the `viewBox`, `width`, `height `settings while also applying a `scale()` to the path in the SVG:

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/58Lbqzh1/14/](https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/58Lbqzh1/14/)