# Can and how do I pass class values to a Fragement in Astro?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, jsx, astrojs

I have the following code, which you can see below. Where I want to pass a class to an imported SVG fragment. Sadly, the class is not forwarded, and the object keeps its old width. How can I solve this? I tried to wrap the fragment, which also did not work and added an unnecessary `div`. Is there a way to add this directly to the raw SVG fragment?

```
---
import iconPlantWilt from '~/assets/icon_plant_wilt.svg?raw';
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
---

<Layout title="404">
  <Fragment class="w-5" set:html={iconPlantWilt} />
</Layout>
```

P.S.: I want to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620422/tailwindcss-svg-icon-wont-resize-properly), but from an imported SVG.

Comment: Change `Fragment` to `div` ? jsx fragments are just arrays... they don't show up in the output html...

Comment: But I just want the SVG and nothing around it. Isn't this adding a div as well?

Comment: yes, that's adding a div. you want to change the string in `iconPlantWilt`? that sounds like more trouble than it's worth...